# How to set file name as date in command prompt

Tags: python, shell, command-line, weblogic-10.x, weblogic11g

I want to run the following `.py` script at the command prompt:

```py
connect('weblogic','welcome','t3://localhost:7001')
exportMetadata(application='soa-infra', server='AdminServer',toLocation='C:\soa11g\New\abc_date.zip', docs='/**')
exit()
```

However, whenever I execute it, I need to create a `.zip` file with whose name contains the sysdate, e.g. `abc_10082015` or `abc_10-08-2015`. How can I do that?

Comment: so you want to execute this python script which generates `abc_date.zip`, and then rename `abc_date.zip` to `abc_10-08-2015.zip` (if that is the current date)? or you want to change the python script so it uses the current date right away?

Comment: yes hoiuji i want that only

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, for your path string, you should prefix `r` so that it is treated as raw string, and `\` is not treated as escape characters.

Secondly, You can use `datetime.datetime.now()` to get the current time , and then use `strftime()` to fromat the date as you want. Example -

```
import datetime
path = r'C:\soa11g\New\abc_%s.zip' % datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%d%m%Y')
connect('weblogic','welcome','t3://localhost:7001')
exportMetadata(application='soa-infra', server='AdminServer',toLocation=path, docs='/**')
exit()
```

If you want , you can also give format as - `'%d_%m_%Y'` to get `'10-08-2015'` . You can get such format details from [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior) .

Comment: Hi Shankar, thanks for your quick reply....... am getting this error.. Problem invoking WLST - Traceback (innermost last):
  File "C:\Oracle\Middleware\oracle_common\common\bin\MDS_BKP.py", line 2, in ?
AttributeError: 'string' object has no attribute 'format'

Comment: Try the latest, seems like WLST's string is a bit different.

Comment: wow thanks anand, if possiable can we set like 10-8-2015, if possible Ple let me know.

Comment: Yes, check the last sentence, you can modify the format string as you want.

Comment: The format string is the argument inside `strftime()` .

Comment: thanks anand, i just want learn this type of the commands. Please let me know any websites that some easy to learn

Comment: for date formatting, the documentation site is - https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior